# Save layer effects as png without picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I save only effects of the layer without saving the actual picture.
I added inner and outer glows to my layer and I need to save only glow effects without nozzle on the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Layers Styles dialog window, under the **Blending Options** set the **Fill Opacity** to 0.

Or You can adjust the **Fill Opacity** at the top of the **Layers Panel**.

[image]

`Fill Opacity` controls the existing pixel data on that layer, whereas `Opacity` controls all aspects of a layer.